# The relative virtual path 'x.resx' is not allowed here

Tags: localization, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

Currently we are trying to localise our rather extensive module, and what use a single resx (for ease of management), WE have written the following code which does return keys however it does leave us with a log message in the event viewer (below the code)

I should also add I cannot use httpcontext.current.server.mappath, as the functions are also used where there is not a httpcontext

Code:

```
Public Shared Function GetString(ByVal key As String, ByVal ParamArray params As String()) As String
            Dim SharedResourceFolder As String = "~/App_GlobalResources/"
            Dim myStr As String = Nothing
            If CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name <> "en-GB" Then
                myStr = Localization.GetString(key, SharedResourceFolder & "Resources." & CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name & ".resx")
                If myStr Is Nothing OrElse myStr = "" Then
                    myStr = Localization.GetString(key, SharedResourceFolder & "Resources." & CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name.Substring(0, 2) & ".resx")
                End If
            End If

            If myStr Is Nothing OrElse myStr = "" Then
                myStr = Localization.GetString(key, SharedResourceFolder & "Resources.resx")
            End If

            If myStr IsNot Nothing AndAlso myStr <> "" Then
                Return String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, myStr, params)
            End If
            Dim res As String = Localization.GetString(key, "Resources.resx", "en-GB")
            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(res) Then
               Return Nothing
            End If
            Return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, res, params)
        End Function
```

Error Message:

> System.ArgumentException: The relative
>   virtual path 'sharedresources.resx' is
>   not allowed here. at
>   System.Web.VirtualPath.FailIfRelativePath()
>   at
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean permitNull) at
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(String
>   virtualPath) at
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.Localization.GetResourceFileCallBack(CacheItemArgs
>   cacheItemArgs) at
>   DotNetNuke.Common.Utilities.DataCache.GetCachedData[TObject](CacheItemArgs
>   cacheItemArgs,
>   CacheItemExpiredCallback
>   cacheItemExpired, Boolean
>   storeInDictionary)

Thankful for any help

---

**UPDATE:**

Changing to a physical path caused me an issue within the DNN core, reverting back to a virtual path and changing a line of code else where in the module Fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess here is that you are using a root relative path, which since you are outside of an HTTP Context the system is failing.  This is based on the stack trace provided and the call to "FailIfRelativePath()" method.

If you look at the DotNetNuke code for Localization.GetString, typically it is provided a physical file path and not a relative path.  To confirm this look at the LocalResourceFile property that is available on any module control that inherits from PortalModuleBase.

Comment: Marking Answer as it helped me find the issue and I cant really see a way of explaining the full extent of it all.